# Sair de um programa c via CMD

Tags: c, cmd

No código a seguir, quando pressiono 9 o programa deve encerrar:

```
case 9:
   exit(0);
```

Após pressionar 9 a tela abaixo no cmd é apresentada, mas após pressionar 9 é apresentada a mensagem: Press  to close this window... e é necessário clicar em uma tecla novamente para encerrar a janela do cmd. A questão é, existe algum comando que feche diretamente a janela do cmd quando pressiono o número 9?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: se você abrir direto a aplicação...vai sair... só q se você estiver no cmd e abrir a aplicação por ele, porque iria fechar o cmd ? e coloque seu código todo para sabermos o que realmente o programa está fazendo

Comment: Isto é C ou C++? Se é C++ esta usando o QtSDK para criar o código? Porque se estiver logo lhe digo que teria que usar o `QCoreApplication::exit(int returnCode);` ou próximo a isto (trocando o int returnCode pelo numero que representará a saída, geralmente 0, assim: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    /* Usando algum sinal emitiria os "eventos" e executaria a.exit() */

    return a.exec();
}`)

Answer (score 3):

```
case 9:
break;
```

Assim já saí... Ou pode usar o comando:

```
system("exit");
```